# tkinter General canvas creating using class

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I know I can do this...

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
#Note if '=' is used, i.e. root.geometry=("800x600")
# then tkinter root(window) does NOT display full area

canv1=tk.Canvas(bg="green", height=150, width=200)
canv1.place(x=20,y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Ideally I'd like to make many canvasses, and as I'm learning about classes, it occurred to me that this could be done employing classes, so I could more easily and more rapidly instantiate a user defined canvas like so...
**canv2 = InstantCanvas(orange, 100, 250)**

I thought this seemed reasonable:

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

class InstantCanvas():
    def __init__(self, background, height, width):
        self = self.tk.Canvas(background, height, width)
        # trying to achieve "my_user_canvas.

#Note if '=' is used, i.e. root.geometry=("800x600")
# then tkinter root(window) does NOT display full area

# Reference canvas, manually made
canv1=tk.Canvas(bg="green", height=150, width=200)
canv1.place(x=20,y=10)

canv2 = InstantCanvas("orange", 100, 250)
canv2.place(x=40,y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

but I get an error...
**AttributeError: 'InstantCanvas' object has no attribute 'tk'**

So I have to put `import tkinter as tk` inside the class **init** function? Seems odd and redundant, but I tried anyway...

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

class InstantCanvas():
    import tkinter as tk
    def __init__(self, background, height, width):
        self = self.tk.Canvas(background, height, width)
        # trying to achieve "my_user_canvas.

#Note if '=' is used, i.e. root.geometry=("800x600")
# then tkinter root(window) does NOT display full area

# Reference canvas, manually made
canv1=tk.Canvas(bg="green", height=150, width=200)
canv1.place(x=20,y=10)

canv2 = InstantCanvas("orange", 100, 250)
canv2.place(x=40,y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Now I get too many argument errors, specifically, **Canvas.**init**() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given**,  but I thought **init** kinda overlooked *self* as a 'hard' argument, but if I leave *self* out, then my **init** function will fail to 'connect' to the instantiated object. So how?

Feedback on why it's not working and how to make it work would be gratefully appreciated. Tq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purpose, it seems that it'd be better to just [subclass](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) `tk.Canvas`, then call `super()` to initialize the canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk


class InstantCanvas(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, background, height, width):
        super().__init__(bg=background, height=height, width=width)
        # trying to achieve "my_user_canvas.


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

# Reference canvas, manually made
canv1 = tk.Canvas(bg="green", height=150, width=200)
canv1.place(x=20, y=10)

canv2 = InstantCanvas("orange", 100, 250)
canv2.place(x=40, y=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This  class InstantCanvas(tk.Canvas): syntax does this in effect, append "tk.Canvas" to my instantiated object variable, 'canv2'? I'm not familiar with this syntax. 
and Unfortunately I still get an error:
**TypeError: super() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)**

Comment: @Micklos Sorry, I had a small typo in my code regarding `super()`. I fixed it, can you try again?

Comment: @Micklos Subclassing allows you to inherit all the properties of the parent class (`tk.Canvas` in this example). So, every `InstantCanvas` object is also a `tk.Canvas` object itself, except you can also add your own properties and methods.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of Subclass. Seemed like the fabled OOP inheritance has appeared, and thanks for the code improvement, but I'm still getting an error...
**Canvas.__init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given** It seems like _self_ is still getting counted as an argument. tkinter's Canvas class I presume can only take 3.

Comment: @Micklos Ok and thank you for pointing that out. I think it has to do with `tk.Canvas` taking keyword argument instead of positional arguments for `bg`, `height`, and `width`. I've edited my answer and it should work now. Can you try again?

Comment: Yes. It works now. A very big thanks!!. :D
So the arguments of tk's Camvas class are kinda like (a fixed number of) **kwargs like parameters and not (a fixed number of) *args like parameters.

Comment: @Micklos Happy to help! If you'd like, you can also upvote my answer to further indicate that it's helpful. Also, if you'd like to learn more about OOP-style inheritance in Python, then I'd recommend the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) (official, but hard to read) and [RealPython's inheritance article](https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/) (easier to understand).